# Carousel animation event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I have an issue with a carousel I have built. It has elements inside a container which are moved 'left' by the size of the visible container when the button with class moveCarouselRight is clicked.

My issue is that when the user clicks too fast, ie double click, the animation seems to fire twice, meaning the elements are not properly fitted in the container as if the first 'left' operation had not completed.

As you can see I tried to fix this with the 'disabled' flag but it seems the second click event is fired before the js from the first event has reached that line of code.

```
var disabled = false;

$('.moveCarouselRight').on('click', function() {

if (!disabled) {

    disabled = true;

    //change css property 'left' depending on container size

    disabled = false;
}
});
```

Link to jsFiddle:
jsfiddle.net/6TPcT/5

Comment: are you sure you have made the disabled flag global

Comment: The disabled flag is global

Comment: Are you using a `<button>` element to receive the click?

Comment: No I am not, the div is an element

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

**JS**

```
$(".moveCarouselRight").dblclick(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**OR**

```
$(".moveCarouselRight").dblclick(function(event){
    return false;
});
```

**OR**

```
$(".moveCarouselRight").one("click", function(event) {
    //do something
});
```

Link: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Good idea although for some reason when i double click on the element, it produces two single clicks as well, Should the prevent default not handle this?

Comment: It should Or you can try `return false;`

Comment: Even when I use return false the js console shows two clicks on the 'click' event handler and one on the 'dblclick' handler

Comment: The one method doesnt do exactly what i want as it binds the event for one click only. Im looking into a way of doing this, but rebinding to the one event at the end of the event.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle link and replicate the problem over there? Seems like the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Which Carousel plugin are you using ?

Comment: Im not using a plugin, I created it myself.
The jsfiddle i made is is http://jsfiddle.net/6TPcT/, although the jQuery isnt working in it, does anyone know how to link them without putting in a script? the menu on the left doesnt seem to help

Comment: You can add External Resources - click on it and add the file url

Comment: I think ive added it in, im not sure its been done properly, can you see where it is wrong?

Comment: Ahh it seems the js works, ive done something else to make this unresponsive, which works in my application, ill have a play....

Comment: jQuery is working...It's something in your logic. I added an alert inside the function and it works. Check your logic again. You might have forgot to copy some other part too ?

Comment: Yea I did the same and it worked, It was the nesting of the divs in the html, the carousel works now

Comment: Do you notice if you click too fast it is not a clean 330pxs moved?

Comment: Link ? You have to update it and send link again. Otherwise I won't be able to access it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by binding a click event to the selector on load:

```
$('.selector').click(moveLeft);
```

In the method I unbound the click event:

```
function moveLeft() {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    //css transition stuff
}
```

Then, I added a listener to the end of the css transitions:

```
$("selector").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd",  function(){
    $(this).siblings('.nextThree').click(moveThreeRight);
});
```

Works a charm :)

Thanks for the help on this